# Reload function by sec variable JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

How do I reload function by a variable of seconds

I tried to do this using `setInterval()`,
But the number of seconds did not change according to the changes within the function, it changed by the first value of the `sec` (30000).

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var sec = 30000;
loadXMLDoc();
function loadXMLDoc(){
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', 'demo.json');
     xhr.responseType = 'text';
     xhr.onload = function(e) {
     if (this.status == 200) {
         console.log('response', this.response); // JSON response
         //document.getElementById("name").textContent = this.response;
         var final = this.response;
         if (final !== ""){
             sec = 10000;
             document.getElementById("name").textContent = final;
             $.post("test2.php", {final: final}, function(data) {
                    // returned from php
             });
         }else{
            sec = 2000;
            document.getElementById("name").textContent = "none";
         }
     }
   }
   xhr.send();
};
loadXMLDoc();
setInterval(loadXMLDoc, sec); 
</script>
```

Comment: var sec = 1000;
    setInterval(loadXMLDoc, sec);

    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    console.log(1)
    }

Comment: try to use this,post errors if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `loadXMLDoc()` 3 times instead of once.

Your structure is like this:

```
// default to 30sec, but this 30 is never used
var sec = 30000;

// loadXMLDoc 1st call, before even defined.
loadXMLDoc();

// define the function
function localXMLDoc(){
   //   code....
   // the following update to sec is never used
   // once the setInterval() is called.
   if (x) {
      sec = 10000;
   } else {
      sec = 2000;
   }
}

// load again
loadXMLDoc();

// continue to call the function every X seconds 
// based on the value set on the 2nd call to loadXMLDoc()
setInterval(loadXMLDoc,sec);
```

A better option would be more like:

```
var delay = null;
function localXMLDoc(){
   // clear any previously scheduled calls
   if (delay) {
      clearTimeout(delay);
   }
   //   code....
   // set a default value for sec
   var sec = 2000;
   if (x) {
      // update sec if needed
      sec = 10000;
   }
   // and reload again
   delay = setTimeout(loadXMLDoc,sec);
}
// load once, when the page has finished loading
window.onload = function() {
   loadXMLDoc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I properly understand your question but I know usually when you use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` function you'd normally use 3000 for seconds
E.g

Display an alert box after 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```